# Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter not working

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to kick out the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and this is not working out. When I use the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter I can see the log message being written(second snippet) when I do not use it the log message is not there(first one). Why? What can I do to see what is wrong? I enabled logging for the or.springframerork.security but I do not see anything  helpfull in there.

```
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Profile({ "cloud" })
@Slf4j
public class CpfsSecurityConfig2 {

    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug("XXXX  Reached configure  XXXX");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.configure(http);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

and using the deprecated WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@Profile({ "cloud" })
@Slf4j
public class CpfsSecurityConfig2 extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        log.debug("XXXX  Reached configure  XXXX");
    }

    // @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        this.configure(http);
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.7.0 with these dependencies

```
<!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsuaa-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Based on the code you've shared, it does reach the `configure` method. There may be something else that is preventing it from being called. Try adding a log statement in `filterChain` (or use the debugger) and see if it reaches there.

Comment: Hi Eleftheria, thanks for replying. I did try but the filterChain does not get invoked. Anything else I could try? I tryed to put a breakpoint into the springSecurityFilterChain() method of the WebSecurityConfiguration ( I can see that hasConfigurers is false and hasFilterChain is true but it did not bring me any further) . Maybe worth mentioning we do this @SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, 
  ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class}) but I don't think that is an issue. What could I further do ?

Comment: It's possible your `CpfsSecurityConfig2` class is not picked up. Is the "cloud" profile enabled? Try simplifying your application to see when the problem starts. If you use a fresh application from start.spring.io then the configuration works as expected. Also note that you can use `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` instead of the `spring-security-oauth2-client` dependency.